# extension to measure, why do they not need to assume countable additivity

Tags: measure-theory

Here they present some necessary conditions in order to be able to extend to a measure:

[image]

But lets say you have a disjoint sequence $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$ whose union **happens** to be in the set you want to explain. Then you surely have to have countable additivity on the function you want to extend to a measure? Can that be read out of these condition? In order for me to prove this I had to assume two things:

1. The empty set was in the set you wanted to extend.
2. Every finite union of $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$ had to be in the set. Now this condition doesn't seem natural? I mean the infinite countable union may be in the set you want to extend, but not some finite union?

Here is my proof where I **assumed** some things:

By E3 we obviously have : $\iota\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \iota(A_n)$.

In order to prove the other inequality, assume for contradiction that:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \iota(A_n) > \iota\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) $, then for one $N$, we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \iota(A_n) > \iota\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \tag{*} $$

**Now I make two assumptions, I assume that $\emptyset$ is in the set, I also assume that $\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n$ is in the set**. Now use E3: with $C = \bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n$. And $C_1=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty,C_2=\emptyset,C_3=\emptyset,\ldots$

Then we get that $\iota\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n\right) \le \iota\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\right)A_n$, but if we use that $\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n$ is in the set and also use E2, we see that this is in direct contradiction with *.

***Is it possible to do this proof without assuming these things?***

Comment: I was tempted to change $l\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n\right)$ to $\ell\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n\right)$, with a cursive $\ell$.  But then I realized that maybe you intended $\iota\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n\right)$.  If so, note that the $\iota$ character can be used. At any rate, it is standard to use \cup in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and \bigcup in things like $\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n$, and I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Comment: Also notice that using \sum instead of \Sigma gives you things like $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N \iota(A_n)$ rather than $\displaystyle\Sigma_{n=1}^N \iota(A_n)$ when the notation is in a displayed, as opposed to inline, setting. The positions of the subscript and superscript differ, as does the size, and also some less conspicuous details. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I'll try to remember these things. Yes it was that special character I meant, but I didn't know how to dinf it.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo "A course in real analysis", by John N. Mcdonald and Neil A. Weiss.

Comment: Do you want to show that $\iota$ is countably additive **on its domain** starting from E1, E2 and E3 ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Yes, if the sets $A_1,A_2....$ are in its domain, and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty$ also happens to be in its domain.

Answer (score 1):

If $\,\mathcal C\,$ is a ring, then **finite additivity** combined with **countable subadditivity** gives **countable additivity**.

Let $C_n$ be pairwise disjoint sets in $\,\mathcal C\,$ whose union $\,C\,$ *also* belongs to $\,\mathcal C\,$.

Then for every $n \in \mathbb N$ one has $$\sum_{k=1}^n \iota (C_k) =\iota \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k \right) \le \iota (C) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \iota (C_k)$$ so it follows that $$\iota (C) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \iota (C_k)$$ Note that, if $A,B \in \mathcal C$ and $A \subset B$, then $\,\iota (A) \le \iota (B)\,$ because $\,\iota (B \setminus A) \ge 0\,$.

Comment: Isnt the inequality you have the one that allready follows from E3? And you used that the finite union was in the domain, it doesnt have to be?

Comment: I supposed $\mathcal C$ is a ring and so is closed with respect to finite union. The equality comes from E2, the 1st inequality from the monotonic property and the 2nd one from E3.

Comment: I think the point id thst before you extend you cant assume it is a ring. And you cant even assume you can take complements yet.

Comment: And the monotonic property do we even have that yet? Musnt that be proved with E3 but then you must assumr you have the emptyset?